# Easier way to see equality of two complex exponential magnitudes

Tags: complex-numbers

I was reading a [paper about wave interference](https://home.uni-leipzig.de/prakphys/pdf/VersuchePhy/Optik/O-10-AUF.pdf) when the following chain of equalities about the wave intensity was given:

$$
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{2} c \epsilon_0 \lvert E_1 + E_2 \rvert^2 \\ \tag{1}
&= \frac{1}{2} c \epsilon_0 RT A_i^2 \lvert \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1) + \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_2) \rvert^2 \\ \tag{2}
&= \frac{1}{2} c \epsilon_0 RT A_i^2 \lvert 1 + \exp(i(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2)) \rvert^2 \\
&= c \epsilon_0 RT A_i^2 (1 + \cos(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2))
\end{align*}
$$

What baffles me is the transition from $(1)$ to $(2)$. It seems like
$$
\lvert \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1) + \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_2) \rvert^2 = \lvert 1 + \exp(i(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2)) \rvert^2
$$

This is not hard to prove by expanding the left hand side exponentials using Euler's formula, using $|z|^2 = \mathrm{Re}^2 z + \mathrm{Im}^2 z$ and finally applying the $\cos$ angle-addition theorem.

However, the way the author wrote it makes me think there is an easier way to see this equality (while it did not feel intuitive to me.) If anyone can enlighten me (is there a general simplification rule hidden here?) or confirm that this neat equality is just a satisfying coincidence, I'd be very happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed there is a way:
$$\lvert \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1) + \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_2) \rvert
=  \lvert \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1) (1 + \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_2 - i \omega t + i \varphi_1) \rvert = \\ \lvert \exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1) \rvert \lvert (1 + \exp(i(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2)) \rvert = \lvert (1 + \exp(i(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2)) \rvert$$
since the first modulus is always equal to one. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I did not think about factoring $\exp(i \omega t - i \varphi_1)$. Thanks very much!